# Flip Effect without Transform or Rotate

Tags: javascript, css

I stumbple upon this Javascript [flip effect](http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2010/03/sponsor-wall-flip-jquery-css/demo.php) page.

When I inspect its obfuscated [source code](http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2010/03/sponsor-wall-flip-jquery-css/jquery.flip.min.js), I can not find css property `transform` or `rotate` .

I want to know how the flip effect is achieved. What CSS properties are involved?

Comment: Why bother looking at the source code when the page is part of a [tutorial](http://tutorialzine.com/2010/03/sponsor-wall-flip-jquery-css/)?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  /* The following code is executed once the DOM is loaded */

  $('.sponsorFlip').click(function() {

    // $(this) point to the clicked .sponsorFlip element (caching it in elem for speed):

    var elem = $(this);

    // data('flipped') is a flag we set when we flip the element:

    if (elem.data('flipped')) {
      // If the element has already been flipped, use the revertFlip method
      // defined by the plug-in to revert to the default state automatically:

      elem.revertFlip();

      // Unsetting the flag:
      elem.data('flipped', false)
    } else {
      // Using the flip method defined by the plugin:

      elem.flip({
        direction: 'lr',
        speed: 350,
        onBefore: function() {
          // Insert the contents of the .sponsorData div (hidden
          // from view with display:none) into the clicked
          // .sponsorFlip div before the flipping animation starts:

          elem.html(elem.siblings('.sponsorData').html());
        }
      });

      // Setting the flag:
      elem.data('flipped', true);
    }
  });

});
```

```css
body {
  /* Setting default text color, background and a font stack */
  font-size: 0.825em;
  color: #666;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.sponsorListHolder {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.sponsor {
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  float: left;
  margin: 4px;
  /* Giving the sponsor div a relative positioning: */
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.sponsorFlip {
  /*  The sponsor div will be positioned absolutely with respect
  to its parent .sponsor div and fill it in entirely */
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  background: url("img/background.jpg") no-repeat center center #f9f9f9;
}
.sponsorFlip:hover {
  border: 1px solid #999;
  /* CSS3 inset shadow: */
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 30px #999 inset;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 30px #999 inset;
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px #999 inset;
}
.sponsorFlip img {
  /* Centering the logo image in the middle of the .sponsorFlip div */
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -70px 0 0 -70px;
}
.sponsorData {
  /* Hiding the .sponsorData div */
  display: none;
}
.sponsorDescription {
  font-size: 11px;
  padding: 50px 10px 20px 20px;
  font-style: italic;
}
.sponsorURL {
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.clear {
  /* This class clears the floats */
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2010/03/sponsor-wall-flip-jquery-css/jquery.flip.min.js"></script>

<div title="Click to flip" class="sponsor">
  <div class="sponsorFlip">
    <img alt="More about google" src="data:image/png;base64,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">
  </div>

  <div class="sponsorData">
    <div class="sponsorDescription">
      The company that redefined web search.
    </div>
    <div class="sponsorURL">
      <a href="http://www.google.com/">http://www.google.com/ </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a jQuery plugin they use to achieve this result. It's called `jquery.flip.min.js` 😉

• Here is a more legible version of their JavaScript code:

```
eval(function(p, a, c, k, e, r) {
  e = function(c) {
    return (c < a ? '' : e(parseInt(c / a))) + ((c = c % a) > 35 ? String.fromCharCode(c + 29) : c.toString(36))
  };
  if (!''.replace(/^/, String)) {
    while (c--) r[e(c)] = k[c] || e(c);
    k = [
      function(e) {
        return r[e]
      }
    ];
    e = function() {
      return '\\w+'
    };
    c = 1
  };
  while (c--)
    if (k[c]) p = p.replace(new RegExp('\\b' + e(c) + '\\b', 'g'), k[c]);
  return p
}('(5($){5 H(a){a.1D.1f[a.1E]=1F(a.1G,10)+a.1H}6 j=5(a){1I({1J:"1g.Z.1K 1L 1M",1N:a})};6 k=5(){7(/*@1O!@*/11&&(1P 1Q.1h.1f.1R==="1S"))};6 l={1T:[0,4,4],1U:[1i,4,4],1V:[1j,1j,1W],1X:[0,0,0],1Y:[0,0,4],1Z:[1k,1l,1l],20:[0,4,4],21:[0,0,A],22:[0,A,A],23:[12,12,12],24:[0,13,0],26:[27,28,1m],29:[A,0,A],2a:[2b,1m,2c],2d:[4,1n,0],2e:[2f,2g,2h],2i:[A,0,0],2j:[2k,2l,2m],2n:[2o,0,R],2p:[4,0,4],2q:[4,2r,0],2s:[0,t,0],2t:[2u,0,2v],2w:[1i,1o,1n],2x:[2y,2z,1o],2A:[1p,4,4],2B:[1q,2C,1q],2D:[R,R,R],2E:[4,2F,2G],2H:[4,4,1p],2I:[0,4,0],2J:[4,0,4],2K:[t,0,0],2L:[0,0,t],2M:[t,t,0],2N:[4,1k,0],2O:[4,S,2P],2Q:[t,0,t],2R:[t,0,t],2S:[4,0,0],2T:[S,S,S],2U:[4,4,4],2V:[4,4,0],9:[4,4,4]};6 m=5(a){T(a&&a.1r("#")==-1&&a.1r("(")==-1){7"2W("+l[a].2X()+")"}2Y{7 a}};$.2Z($.30.31,{u:H,v:H,w:H,x:H});$.1s.32=5(){7 U.1t(5(){6 a=$(U);a.Z(a.B(\'1u\'))})};$.1s.Z=5(i){7 U.1t(5(){6 c=$(U),3,$8,C,14,15,16=k();T(c.B(\'V\')){7 11}6 e={I:(5(a){33(a){W"X":7"Y";W"Y":7"X";W"17":7"18";W"18":7"17";34:7"Y"}})(i.I),y:m(i.D)||"#E",D:m(i.y)||c.z("19-D"),1v:c.J(),F:i.F||1w,K:i.K||5(){},L:i.L||5(){},M:i.M||5(){}};c.B(\'1u\',e).B(\'V\',1).B(\'35\',e);3={s:c.s(),n:c.n(),y:m(i.y)||c.z("19-D"),1x:c.z("36-37")||"38",I:i.I||"X",G:m(i.D)||"#E",F:i.F||1w,o:c.1y().o,p:c.1y().p,1z:i.1v||39,9:"9",1a:i.1a||11,K:i.K||5(){},L:i.L||5(){},M:i.M||5(){}};16&&(3.9="#3a");$8=c.z("1b","3b").8(3c).B(\'V\',1).3d("1h").J("").z({1b:"1A",3e:"3f",p:3.p,o:3.o,3g:0,3h:3i});6 f=5(){7{1B:3.9,1x:0,3j:0,u:0,w:0,x:0,v:0,N:3.9,O:3.9,P:3.9,Q:3.9,19:"3k",3l:\'3m\',n:0,s:0}};6 g=5(){6 a=(3.n/13)*25;6 b=f();b.s=3.s;7{"q":b,"1c":{u:0,w:a,x:a,v:0,N:\'#E\',O:\'#E\',o:(3.o+(3.n/2)),p:(3.p-a)},"r":{v:0,u:0,w:0,x:0,N:3.9,O:3.9,o:3.o,p:3.p}}};6 h=5(){6 a=(3.n/13)*25;6 b=f();b.n=3.n;7{"q":b,"1c":{u:a,w:0,x:0,v:a,P:\'#E\',Q:\'#E\',o:3.o-a,p:3.p+(3.s/2)},"r":{u:0,w:0,x:0,v:0,P:3.9,Q:3.9,o:3.o,p:3.p}}};14={"X":5(){6 d=g();d.q.u=3.n;d.q.N=3.y;d.r.v=3.n;d.r.O=3.G;7 d},"Y":5(){6 d=g();d.q.v=3.n;d.q.O=3.y;d.r.u=3.n;d.r.N=3.G;7 d},"17":5(){6 d=h();d.q.w=3.s;d.q.P=3.y;d.r.x=3.s;d.r.Q=3.G;7 d},"18":5(){6 d=h();d.q.x=3.s;d.q.Q=3.y;d.r.w=3.s;d.r.P=3.G;7 d}};C=14[3.I]();16&&(C.q.3n="3o(D="+3.9+")");15=5(){6 a=3.1z;7 a&&a.1g?a.J():a};$8.1d(5(){3.K($8,c);$8.J(\'\').z(C.q);$8.1e()});$8.1C(C.1c,3.F);$8.1d(5(){3.M($8,c);$8.1e()});$8.1C(C.r,3.F);$8.1d(5(){T(!3.1a){c.z({1B:3.G})}c.z({1b:"1A"});6 a=15();T(a){c.J(a)}$8.3p();3.L($8,c);c.3q(\'V\');$8.1e()})})}})(3r);', 62, 214, '|||flipObj|255|function|var|return|clone|transparent||||||||||||||height|top|left|start|second|width|128|borderTopWidth|borderBottomWidth|borderLeftWidth|borderRightWidth|bgColor|css|139|data|dirOption|color|999|speed|toColor|int_prop|direction|html|onBefore|onEnd|onAnimation|borderTopColor|borderBottomColor|borderLeftColor|borderRightColor|211|192|if|this|flipLock|case|tb|bt|flip||false|169|100|dirOptions|newContent|ie6|lr|rl|background|dontChangeColor|visibility|first|queue|dequeue|style|jquery|body|240|245|165|42|107|140|230|224|144|indexOf|fn|each|flipRevertedSettings|content|500|fontSize|offset|target|visible|backgroundColor|animate|elem|prop|parseInt|now|unit|throw|name|js|plugin|error|message|cc_on|typeof|document|maxHeight|undefined|aqua|azure|beige|220|black|blue|brown|cyan|darkblue|darkcyan|darkgrey|darkgreen||darkkhaki|189|183|darkmagenta|darkolivegreen|85|47|darkorange|darkorchid|153|50|204|darkred|darksalmon|233|150|122|darkviolet|148|fuchsia|gold|215|green|indigo|75|130|khaki|lightblue|173|216|lightcyan|lightgreen|238|lightgrey|lightpink|182|193|lightyellow|lime|magenta|maroon|navy|olive|orange|pink|203|purple|violet|red|silver|white|yellow|rgb|toString|else|extend|fx|step|revertFlip|switch|default|flipSettings|font|size|12px|null|123456|hidden|true|appendTo|position|absolute|margin|zIndex|9999|lineHeight|none|borderStyle|solid|filter|chroma|remove|removeData|jQuery'.split('|'), 0, {}))
```